# How to determine selected value for drop down lists in asp.net MVC View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

New to asp.net MVC.  I have a table that has multiple fields.  I want to build input rules where the user has to select a value either in Field1's or Field2's drop down list.  The user will not be able to post if a value is selected for both Field1 and Field2 simultaneously or if neither Field1 or Field2 have a selected value.

Part of my dilemma is in deciding where the input logic or rules should be recorded (Controller vs View)?  As I understand it, best practice is to keep the Controller simple and "skinny" so do I place the input rules in the View using Razor?  If so, how?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Here is the model:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderID {get; set;} 
    public string Field1 {get; set;} 
    public string Field2 {get; set;} 
    //other properties 
}
```

I use viewbags in the Controller to create the dropdownlists:

```
// GET: Order/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
     ViewBag.Field1 = new SelectList(db.Field1.OrderBy(x => x.Name), "Name", "Name");            
     ViewBag.Field2 = new SelectList(db.Field2.OrderBy(z => z.Clip), "Clip", "Clip");            
     return View();
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Field1, (SelectList)ViewBag.Field1, "Select one...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })                
      </div>
</div>                                                               
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Field2, (SelectList)ViewBag.Field2, "Select one...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })                
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the validation rule is a part of business logic/requirement then it should be implemented in the backend/server side. Remember that users can post data to your routes using tools like postman etc, hence bypassing your UI/View validation. Javascript/UI validation to show/hide input is an extra step that you can take to make it easier for your users. If this validation only occurs at one place of your application, I'd keep it simple, stupid (KISS) and just validate inside a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(OrderViewModel order)
{
    var bothFieldsAreEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(order.Field1) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(order.Field2);
    var bothFieldsAreFilled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(order.Field1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(order.Field2);

    if (bothFieldsAreEmpty || bothFieldsAreFilled)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please select either Field1 or Field2, not both.");
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    // Do something
    }
    return View(order);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the Sage advice!  Learned a great deal from your simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.  I explain in the code where to put each item:

View:

```
@*put model reference here*@
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>IndexValid9</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedA,
                new SelectList(Model.TableAList, "Value", "Text"))
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedA)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedB,
                new SelectList(Model.TableAList, "Value", "Text"))
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedB)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Controller Model

```
//You can put this in a model folder
public class FieldViewModel
{
    public FieldViewModel()
    {
        TableAList = Utilites.GetTableAList();
        TableBList = Utilites.GetTableBList();
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> TableAList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> TableBList { get; set; }
    public int SelectedA { get; set; }
    public int SelectedB { get; set; }
}

//You can put this in its own folder
public class Utilites
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> GetTableAList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

        try
        {
            using (BreazEntities31 entity = new BreazEntities31())
            {
                entity.TableAs.
                    OrderBy(r => r.Text).ToList().ForEach(r => list.Add(
                    new SelectListItem { Text = r.Text, Value = r.Value.ToString() }));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }

        //add <select> to first item
        list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "" });

        return list;
    }

    public static List<SelectListItem> GetTableBList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

        try
        {
            using (BreazEntities31 entity = new BreazEntities31())
            {
                entity.TableBs.
                    OrderBy(r => r.Text).ToList().ForEach(r => list.Add(
                    new SelectListItem { Text = r.Text, Value = r.Value.ToString() }));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }

        //add <select> to first item
        list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "" });

        return list;
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexValid9(FieldViewModel fieldViewModel)
    {
       //put breakpoint here to see selected values from both ddl, interrogate fieldViewModel
       return View();
    }

    public ActionResult IndexValid9()
    {
        FieldViewModel fieldViewModel = new FieldViewModel();
        return View(fieldViewModel);
    }
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Text] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Value] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TableB]    Script Date: 6/27/2017 3:59:07 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Text] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Value] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([Id], [Text], [Value]) VALUES (1, N'tableaTxt', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([Id], [Text], [Value]) VALUES (2, N'tableaTxt2', 2)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TableA] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Id], [Text], [Value]) VALUES (1, N'tablebTxt', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Id], [Text], [Value]) VALUES (2, N'tablebTxt2', 2)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TableB] OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation logic is usually implemented in the View Model class using data annotations. However for your case you can use a custom validation attribute like the following

```
    public class OnlyOneValueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string TheOtherPropertyName { get; private set; }

        public OnlyOneValueAttribute(string theOtherPropertyName)
        {
            TheOtherPropertyName = theOtherPropertyName;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var theProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(validationContext.MemberName);
            var theValue = theProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null) as string;

            var theOtherProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(TheOtherPropertyName);
            var theOtherValue = theOtherProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null) as string;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(theValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(theOtherValue) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(theValue) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(theOtherValue))
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

You can then use it in your model

```
    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        [OnlyOneValue(nameof(Field2))]
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        [OnlyOneValue(nameof(Field1))]
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
        //other properties 
    }
```

And in your controller you test on you model state validity

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test(Order model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //OK logic
            }
            return View();
        }
```

However I suggest you review the implementation of this use case for UX convenience.

Hope this helps.